# Функция mail с вложением

Tags: email, php

Есть код отправки письма с вложением 
с такой вот функцией (в нете взял)

```
function xmail( $from, $to, $subj, $text, $filename) {
$f         = fopen($filename,"rb");
$un        = strtoupper(uniqid(time()));
$head      = "From: $from\n";
$head     .= "To: $to\n";
$head     .= "Subject: $subj\n";
$head     .= "X-Mailer: PHPMail Tool\n";
$head     .= "Reply-To: $from\n";
$head     .= "Mime-Version: 1.0\n";
$head     .= "Content-Type:multipart/mixed;";
$head     .= "boundary=\"----------".$un."\"\n\n";
$zag       = "------------".$un."\nContent-Type:text/html;\n";
$zag      .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n$text\n\n";
$zag      .= "------------".$un."\n";
$zag      .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream;";
$zag      .= "name=\"".basename($filename)."\"\n";
$zag      .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\n";
$zag      .= "Content-Disposition:attachment;";
$zag      .= "filename=\"".basename($filename)."\"\n\n";
$zag      .= chunk_split(base64_encode(fread($f,filesize($filename))))."\n";

return @mail("$to", "$subj", $zag, $head);
}
xmail('sender',$adress,$head1,$m,'img/'.$file_name);
```

Все посылается и картинка приходит даже имя пишется картинки но картинка сама приходит битая кто может помочь?

Comment: А можно функцию в код превратить? Никто читать не будет иначе

Comment: Попробуйте прочитать файл через функцию file_get_contents()

Comment: поставил не помогает все приходимт даже вес файла пишется но формат неверный

Comment: вместо application/octet-stream попробуйте image/jpeg

Comment: Это везде так или только у вас на хостинге/лок. сервере?

Comment: везде не знаю на хостинге так а локадльно не проверял все вроде доставляется только какая то закавыка файли не читаются после получения хотя и вес и название и даже формат определяются почти всю голову сломал)

Comment: @Mixail, я так понимаю, что добить самому - это у вас уже дело принципа. )) Но если устанете, то [вот тут найдёте](http://www.phpclasses.org/search.html?words=phpmailer&x=0&y=0&go_search=1) готовые классы.

Comment: вместо application/octet-stream поставить  image/jpeg не помогает тоже

Answer (score 1):

Отправьте эту картинку себе через обычный почтовик, и сравните исходный код полученного письма с кодом письма из вашего скрипта.  
Сравнивать надо исходные коды полученных писем, а потом править скрипт.

Comment: класно! а как посмотреть код скрипта если отправлять по почтовику?

Comment: Смотреть и сравнивать надо исходные КОДЫ ПОЛУЧЕННЫХ ПИСЕМ.
Посмотреть код письма можно по разному, в зависимости от почтовика.
В mail.ru меню: "Ещё, Скачать на компьютер", затем открываете файл письма блокнотом.
В Outlook Express: "Свойства, Подробно, Исходное сообщение", или же "Файл, Сохранить как", далее открываете блокнотом.
В Thunderbird "Ctrl+U".
Только после сравнения смотрите свой скрипт, ведь код одного из писем генерирует именно он, а код другого письма генерирует почтовик.

Answer (score 0):

Картинка приходит битая по двум причинам:
 1. Она не была загружена на ваш сервер.
 2. Не правильно указан путь до файла.

Решение:
 1. Удостовериться что картинка загружена.
 2. Путь к картинке указывать $filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/путь_до_картинки_от корня_сайта";

В остальном скрипт полностью рабочий.